# How to configure and run Hadoop Pipes on Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: hadoop

I am newbie in Linux Hadoop. I am looking for guidance to make Hadoop up and running for writing C++ tasks. I tried to install Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode using tutorial:

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

It works fine with Java, but I am getting this error while running c++ wordcount example:

```
12/05/03 18:23:00 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost/user/c1048267/books
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

Please also guide me if there is particular software, hardware or configuration requirement. Currently I am on Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit, Hadoop-0.20.2 and Java_Sun_6. Does this platform support Hadoop pipes? If not please guide me then.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to configure your HADOOP_CLASSPATH to include all libraries related to Pipes and then compile them, creating a MAKEFILE for it:

```
CC = g++
HADOOP_INSTALL = /home/hadoop/hadoop
PLATFORM = Linux-i386-32
CPPFLAGS = -m32 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include

wordcount: wordcount.cpp
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes \
-lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

You need for this in every machine of your cluster **libssl** and **g++**. To compile and run the wordcount example, then you can run:

```
make  wordcount
```

Then, you have to copy the output binary for your /bin directory in **HDFS**:

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir bin                    
hadoop dfs -put  wordcount   bin/wordcount
```

Run the program with:

```
hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true  \ 
               -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true \
               -input dft1  -output dft1-out  \
               -program bin/wordcount
```

The second thing that I saw is this:

```
See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String). Exception in thread "main"    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: **Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost/user/c1048267/books** at
```

Are you sure that you have that directory in HDFS?
Best wishes

For the completed guide, see this [link](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C++_Programs_on_Hadoop)